# NSTimer runs only once

Tags: nstimer

I created timer for my application, but timer runs only once and after that is stopped.

Below is my code:

```
moveobjecttimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Repeats is setted on YES but timer runs only once.

My question is: How is possible create timer which is running in continous loop without stopping?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your code is executed in a separate `NSThread`? In this case, the timer is added to the run loop of this thread. If the thread is then terminated, before the timer could fire a 2nd time, the timer fires only once.

Comment: I add additional code, added timer on runloop and to main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I add additional code, added the timer on runloop and to main thread.Also added loging and according log,the timer is active during all time.

Below is code: NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
        self.moveobjecttimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(moveObject) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

```
    [runloop addTimer:moveobjecttimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [runloop addTimer:moveobjecttimer forMode:UITrackingRunLoopMode];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(moveobjecttimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    BOOL timerstate = [moveobjecttimer isValid];
    NSLog(@"Timer validity is: %@",timerstate?@"YES":@"NO");
```

The animation is shown only once again.